# How to identify the last data point in a row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The below question was already asked by another user. I have a variation of the same question. I need to know the column header for the last data value if multiple data points exist for that row. The below formula will return the first data point <>"" but I need the last data point that is <>"". Please non-VBA formulas only.

```
=IF(COUNTA($E2:$T2)=0,"",INDEX($E$1:$T$1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($E2:$T2<>"",0),0)))
```

[Click to see example of needed result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs2n9.jpg)
[image: Click to see example of needed result]

Update 1:

Because my question is not clear, so I post second example

Example 2

Because row 2, there is value 1 at Item 04 so the Get Item Name = Item 04. It is random and have a large number of columns (500).

The problem:

I would like to have a way to get a column header if there is any value input to the cells under that header. Please note that if at row 2 and column 1 has value, then other cell of row 2 will not have any value (other than 0).

It is hard to explain the problem in words so I have created an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work in all cases to get the last numeric data point in a row and to return the column header...even if there are blank values in-between data points:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(A5:J5),A$1:J$1)
```

Note: this assumes the data are in columns A through J, and that the column headers are in the first row. Adjust accordingly.

Comment: I like this but trying it, it does skip the null values but it also skips the '0' values.  using the values that the OP gave on row 5 it gives the wrong output.

Comment: @ScottCraner IFixed it.

Comment: Yup, Works like promised.

Comment: This worked perfectly! And yes because these are revisions, I will not have a blank value between data points but could have a 0. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your data starts in A1 then put this in A2 and copy down:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,0,COUNTA(B2:F2))
```

Comment: @ExcelHero I assumed (yes I know assume means) that since they are revisions that the data would be consistent across the rows.  And as the example does not show any blanks I did not address them. It is an good question for OP.